# A rod with density $\delta(x) = x^2+2x$ lies on the $x$-axis between $x= 0$ and $x= 2$. Find the mass and center of mass of the rod.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, physics

A rod with density $\delta(x) = x^2 + 2x$ lies on the x-axis between $x= 0$ and $x= 2$. Find the mass and center of mass of the rod.

I found mass by integrating $\int_0^2 \left(x^2+2x\right)$ and got 20/3.

I need help finding the center of mass.

Comment: The moment $M$ of the rod about $x=0$ is $\int_0^2 x(x^2+2x)\,dx$. The centre of mass is at $\frac{M}{m}$, where $m$ is the mass.

Comment: I got (28/3)/(20/3) which comes out to 14 but it's wrong

Comment: It simplifies to $\frac{7}{5}$, which is $1.4$.

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass is in essence the average $x$

$$ \int_0^2 x \delta(x)\,{\rm d}x = x_{cm} \int_0^2 \delta(x)\,{\rm d}x $$

$$ x_{cm} = \dfrac{\int_0^2 x \delta(x)\,{\rm d}x}{\int_0^2 \delta(x)\,{\rm d}x} $$

$$ x_{cm} = \dfrac{ \frac{28}{3} } {\frac{20}{3} } = \frac{7}{5} = 1.4$$

Comment: This is the result of dividing a first-moment integral by a "zero-th" moment integral.  It is analogous to finding the "weighted average" for a discrete distribution, a familiar example of which is "class average" for an exam, where we divide $ \ n_1 \cdot s_1 + n_2 \cdot s_2 + \ldots + n_N \cdot s_N \ $ (the number  $ \ n_i \ $ of each score $ \ s_i \ $ ) by the total number of scores $ \ n_1 + n_2 + \ldots + n_N \ , $ the first moment of the score distribution divided by its "zeroth" moment.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.